# Swap keys of nested dictionaries

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I have a dictionary as follows:

Each key has a dictionary associated with it.

```
dict_sample = {'a': {'d0': '1', 'd1': '2', 'd2': '3'}, 'b': {'d0': '1'}, 'c': {'d1': '1'}}
```

I need the output as follows:

```
output_dict = {'d0': {'a': 1, 'b': 1}, 'd1': {'a': 2, 'c': 1}, 'd2': {'a': 3}}
```

I'd appreciate any help on the pythonic way to achieve this. Thank You !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `dict.setdefault` on a new dict with a nested loop:

```
d = {}
# for each key and sub-dict in the main dict
for k1, s in dict_sample.items():
    # for each key and value in the sub-dict
    for k2, v in s.items():
        # this is equivalent to d[k2][k1] = int(v), except that when k2 is not yet in d,
        # setdefault will initialize d[k2] with {} (a new dict)
        d.setdefault(k2, {})[k1] = int(v)
```

`d` would become:

```
{'d0': {'a': 1, 'b': 1}, 'd1': {'a': 2, 'c': 1}, 'd2': {'a': 3}}
```

Comment: Thank You ! Could you explain the code briefly. I am new to python.

Comment: You're welcome. I've updated my code with inline comments that should help explain it.

Answer (score 3):

I believe this produces the desired output

```
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> d = defaultdict(dict)
>>>
>>> dict_sample = {'a': {'d0': '1', 'd1': '2', 'd2': '3'}, 'b': {'d0': '1'}, 'c': {'d1': '1'}}
>>>
>>> for key, value in dict_sample.items():
...     for k, v in value.items():
...         d[k][key] = v
...
>>> d
defaultdict(<class 'dict'>, {'d0': {'a': '1', 'b': '1'}, 'd1': {'a': '2', 'c': '1'}, 'd2': {'a': '3'}})
```

Comment: Thank You !. What is defaultdict ? How does it help as opposed to simply initializing d = {}. I am not following it. Kindly explain.

Comment: @ChandanSingh https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict